# Elasticsearch processes memory and cpu load

Tags: elasticsearch, process, searchkick, cpu-load

I'm running rails gem Searchkick to access Elasticsearch rpm (centos6) installation and I see several Elasticsearch processes having different names (through NewRelic) such as: 
java (elasticsearch) 256MB 
freeBSD (elasticsearch) 15MB 
99 (elasticsearch) 9 MB 
linux64 (elasticsearch) 9MB 
ru1 (elasticsearch) 1MB 
ru (elasticsearch) 0MB

What are all these processes for? What does those names mean? How can I manage them? What's happening at all?!